# Переопределить переменную WebSockets

Tags: javascript, websocket

Нужно переопределить переменную id на ту, которую отправит клиент. Я бы хотел конечно сразу присваивать id, который отправит пользователь, но не знаю как сделать отправку на сервер до того момента, как определиться переменная id, так как эта функция срабатывает сразу при соединении, именно поэтому решил сначала присваивать рандомный id, а потом уже переопределять. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

```
var clients = {};

webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws) {

  var id = Math.random(); //клиенту присваивается рандомный id
  clients[id] = ws;
  console.log("новое соединение " + id);

  ws.on('message', function(message) { //здесь клиент передает информацию, в данном случае пользователь вводит какой-нибудь id, нужно чтобы цифра которую отправит пользователь была новым id, то есть нужно переопределить переменную id которая при коннекте с сервером была создана.
    id = message; //пробовал так, но все равно остается тот, рандомный id который определился здесь " var id = Math.random();"

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так.

```
var clients = {};

    webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws) {

      ws.on('message', function(message) { /
        clients[message] = ws; 

    });

});
```